# How to list all tables' name in MSAccess database file using sql query in java?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I've getting some code here

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + f.getPath() + ";";
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    Statement st=conn.createStatement();
                    String query="SELECT name FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type=1 AND Flags=0";
                    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
                    ArrayList<String> tableNames=new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        String name=rs.getString(1);
                        tableNames.add(name);
                    }
```

but there has some problem

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'."
```

and I searched for this problem and Just found this: [social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/…](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cd6eadd-2d9d-4dbd-8920-e2847a74f80a/retrieve-all-msaccess-table-names-using-openrowset-funtion-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql) "
Because MSysObjects is a system table in Access, the Admin user does not have permission to read data in it". 
I read the answer, but in fact, I want to access permission by programming, does anyone can help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Access does not allow to query `MSysObjects`. Did you follow the steps in the article to give your user the adequate permission?

Anyway JDBC also has an own API which allows you to read database metadata:

```
 Connection conn = ...
 DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
 ResultSet rs = metaData.getTables(null, null, "%", null); 
 while (rs.next()) {
      String name = rs.getString(3); // see javadoc of DatabaseMetaData
      tableNames.add(name);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have not tried the answer in article because It have to obtain permission by user but not the programm (suppose I just have the file name and path only in the programm). Besides, I have tried your code and It's work, but  there are too many table names not only the names I want but also system tables like 'MSysAccessObjects','MSysQueries',etc. How can I solve this problem? Thanks again.

Comment: @yao take a look at the parameters of method `getTables`. Passing non null params might allow you to limit the returned tables to the interesting ones...